# Comparison of a Variable in an IF statement in Bash scripting

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sh

I am working on a bash script, and I want my variable that is passed in as a parameter to the script (a value 0-15), to sort numerically. My thought was to add a 0 before any value less than 10. This is because this variable will be used to name a file and services. Therefore, it will be sorted alphabetically (i.e. clonos-fix@pci-XX-bay-00, clonos-fix@pci-XX-bay-01, . . . clonos-fix@pci-XX-bay-10). Currently it is being sorted -10, -11. . . -15, -0, -01 . . . -09.

The if statement doesn't work. How do I fix this, or is there a better way to go about this?

The script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo [phy_sim_add.sh]: $1 $2 >> /CLONOS/log.txt

port_path=$(echo $1 | grep -P "pci.*port-\d*:\d*" -o)
port=$(echo $port_path | grep -P "port-\d*:\d*" -o)
phy_dir=$(ls "/sys/devices/"$port_path)
phy_num_full=$(echo $phy_dir | grep -P "phy-\d*:\d*" -o)
phy_num=$(echo $phy_num_full | grep -P "\d*\Z" -o)


echo [phy_sim_add.sh]: phy_num = $phy_num port_num = $port>> /CLONOS/log.txt 

echo $phy_num >> /CLONOS/tmp.txt

if (($phy_num < 9)); then
    #$phy_num = "0"$phy_num
    echo YAY >> /CLONOS/tmp.txt
fi

echo $phy_num >> /CLONOS/tmp.txt

mkdir -p /tmp/clonos_ports/$port/$phy_num

ln /dev/$2 /dev/pci-XX-bay-$phy_num


/bin/systemctl start clonos-fix@pci-XX-bay-$phy_num
```

I've tried the if statement like:

```
if [[]]; then
~~~~~~
fi
```

and

```
if (()); then
~~~~~~~~
fi
```

and

```
if [[]]
then
~~~~~~~~~
fi
```

Nothing has worked.

Comment: `sort -n` can do this

Comment: How exactly does it fail? "Doesn't work" is not a useful description of a problem. Does it give the wrong result under some conditions, and if so what's the result and the conditions under which it occurs? Does it give an error message, and if so what's the exact message? BTW, I don't know if it's related, but there are a whole bunch of things here that should be double-quoted -- [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out most of them, but also `[phy_sim_add.sh]:` will be treated as a filename wildcard unless it's quoted.

Comment: please update the question to include ... 1) a sample script invocation so we can see what goes in `$1` and `$2`, 2) the expected results of the script (contents of the `/CLONOS/*.txt` files, the expected `mkdir`, `ln` and `systemctl` calls), and 3) the actual `if....` attempts; **note:** diagnosing a `if [[<sometest>]]` issue is heavily dependent on seeing the *exact* code as there are several syntax issues that cause the test to 'fail'

Answer (score 0):

As erik258 already commented, sort -n will give proper sort order for files, but only as long as there is nothing after the numeric value.  However, ls default will give you what you have observed.  As you have chosen, adding a 0 prefix to the smaller integers ensures ls reporting in the default order matches your intended numeric order.

Hence, if $2 is the specified numeric ID (0-15), phy_num can be correctly formatted this way:

```
phy_num=$(echo "$2" | awk '{ printf("%02d\n", $1 ) ; }' )
```

This eliminates the need for the if statement which is giving you issues.